# Measurable Function bounded by Borel Functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f \colon \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be Lebesgue measurable. Show that there exist Borel measurable functions $g, h \colon \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that  $g(x) \leq f(x) \leq h(x) \ \  \forall x\in \mathbb R$ and $m(\{ x: g(x) \neq h(x) \}) = 0$

**I try** by using simple approximation lemma that tells me i can find simple functions $\varphi$ and $\psi$ such that $\varphi \leq f \leq \psi$ and $0 \leq \psi - \varphi < \epsilon $ on $E$

On the other hand, since $E$ has finite measure, there exist an $F_{\sigma}$ set $F$ and $G_{\delta}$ set $G$ , both Borel sets, such that $F \subset E \subset G$ and $m^*(F) = m^*(E) = m^*(G)$

Now i can define $g$ and $h$ using characteristic functions on $F$ and $G$ but i am not sure if i am right or how to write the functions?

Any help, Thanks.

Comment: There is a slightly stronger result which states that every Lebesgue measurable functions is a.e. equal to a Borel measurable function. This follows from the fact that the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets is the completion of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @Reveillark: I thought about that too, but I am not actually sure that this result is stronger. But one can probably adapt the proof. Nevertheless, **this question was already asked today or yesterday**, here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457184/a-question-about-measurable-function. But we can't close as a duplicate, since the other question has no answer.

Comment: @Reveillark: The problem with that is that we want to have $f \leq g \leq h$ **everywhere**, not almost everywhere.

Comment: @PhoemueX Whoops, that's what I get for reading it too fast :)

Comment: This statement is not true (unless we don't allow $g,h$ to take values $\{\pm\infty\}$).

Answer (score 1):

Assume, without loss of generality that $f$ takes values in the interval $[0,1]$.

Observe that for each $x$, $f(x)=\sup_{r\in{\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)}}r\cdot 1_{A(r)}(x)$, where ${\Bbb Q}$ denotes the rational numbers and $A(r):=f^{-1}((r,1])$ is Lebesgue measurable. As such there is, for each $r\in{\Bbb Q}\cap(0,1)$, a Borel set $B(r)\subset A(r)$ with $\lambda(A(r)\setminus B(r))=0$. (Here $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure.) The recipe $\varphi(x):=\sup_{r\in{\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)}}r\cdot 1_{B(r)}(x)$ defines a Borel measurable function $\varphi$ with $\varphi(x)\le f(x)$ for all $x$, and $\lambda(\{x:\varphi(x)<f(x)\})\le\lambda(\cup_{r\in{\Bbb Q\cap(0,1)}}[A(r)\setminus B(r)])=0$. The same argument applied to $1-f$ yields a Borel function $\psi$ with $f\le\psi$ everywhere, and $\lambda(\{x:f(x)<\psi(x)\})=0$. Clearly $\lambda(\{\varphi<\psi\})\le\lambda(\{\varphi<f\})+\lambda(\{f<\psi\})=0$.